# I cannot seem to loop again after selecting default in switch case in C

Tags: c, switch-statement

hello guys I coded something like kfc menu,and I got it to work(finally),but when I input something other than numbers for "menu",eg:the letter "A", I just can't get it to loop again to normal,instead it finishes the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char counter='y';
    float totalprice=0;

    while (counter=='Y'  ||  counter=='y')
    {
        int menu;
        float price=0;

        printf("\nplease select from menu:");
        scanf (" %i", &menu);

        switch(menu)
        {
          case  1: {
              printf("\none hotbox1 =RM10.50");
              totalprice=totalprice+10.50;
              break;
          }
          case   2: {
              printf ("\none hotbox2=RM10.60");
              totalprice=totalprice+10.60;
              break;
          }
          case   3:{
              printf ("\none hotbox3=RM10.70");
              totalprice=totalprice+10.70;
              break;
          }
          default : {
              printf ("\nplease enter proper number please:");
              scanf("%2f", &menu);
              break;
          }
        }

        printf("\n\nadd order?(Y/N):");
        scanf (" %c", &counter);
    }

    printf("\n\nThe total price is: %f", totalprice);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need braces in your case statements.

Comment: @ChristianTernus - but it can help with understanding; and sometimes the extra scope even comes in handy

Answer (score 1):

You should use `fgets()` ([reference here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/)) first and then `sscanf()` ([reference here)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/), checking it's return value to see if it's a number.

```
char inputBuffer[MAX_BUFFER];

do
{
    fgets(inputBuffer, MAX_BUFFER, stdin);
}
while(sscanf(inputBuffer, "%d", &menu) != 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You scanf with `%f` in the default case, I am fairly certain that is for floats. Use `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `scanf("%2f", &menu);`

Answer (score 0):

When `scanf("%i", &menu)` tries to read an integer from the input, it finds `A`, which it cannot interpret as a number, so it does not read it(*).  Then the next scanf continues reading the input from when the other left off and happily reads the letter 'A'.  Since you loop as long as the read letter is either 'y' or 'Y' (which A is neither), it exits the loop.

(*) read up on the documentation of scanf to see how to tell if it encountered an error.

Note: `scanf("%i", &menu)` should be `scanf("%d", &menu) as`%d` is the formatting symbol for integers.

One solution would be to change the loop condition to:

```
while (counter!='N' && counter!='n')
{
  ...
}
```

This way you end the loop only if an explicit 'N' or 'n' is inputted.

Note: it won't help if you accidentally type 'n' for the menu item, so see the comment about the error handling above.

Comment: I think I understand what you guys are saying,but actually it just ends my whole program,rather than looping back..any way to loop back even after selecting default?

Comment: @HafizSyazwan - first try entering the letter 'y' on the menu and see if it loops back as you want.  If it does, you need to understand why it loops on that input, but not on 'A'.  Once you understand that you will be in a better position to implement the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Switch in C does not support char in switch-case. Before you start switch-case validate the user input. If it is a number go into switch case otherwise display a user message to enter only numeric value

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you debug this by printing out the value of "counter" at various points in the loop (i.e. after you  read it in, at the bottom of the loop, etc.).  This will give you visibility into what your code is doing.

Comment: it should be in comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main()
{
    char counter;
    float totalprice=0;
    int menu=0;
    do
    {
        printf("\n1. one hotbox1=RM10.50");
        printf("\n2. one hotbox2=RM10.60");
        printf("\n3. one hotbox3=RM10.70");
        printf("\nplease select from menu:");
        scanf ("%d", &menu);
        switch(menu)
        {
          case 1:
              printf("\none hotbox1 =RM10.50");
              totalprice=totalprice+10.50;
              break;
          case 2:
              printf ("\none hotbox2=RM10.60");
              totalprice=totalprice+10.60;
              break;
          case 3:
              printf ("\none hotbox3=RM10.70");
              totalprice=totalprice+10.70;
              break;
          default :
              printf ("\nplease enter proper number please:");
              scanf("%d", &menu);
        }
        printf("\n\nadd more order?(Y/N):");
        fflush(stdin);      //to empty the input stream.
        scanf("%c",&counter);
    }while(tolower(counter) != 'n'); //tolower returns the lowercase character.

    printf("\n\nThe total price is: %.2f", totalprice);
    return 0;
}
```